# How to center a image when visualized in small windows, tablets and smartphone

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web site and on the top I have, from left to right, a image as logo, the menu items and some social icons.
When I resize the window, or if I see the web site on smartphone and tablet, the logo stays on the left, the menu become a icon (on the right) and the social icons go under logo and menu icon on the center.

Till now is everything ok, but I need the logo to go on the center.
I tried various solutions found here, but when they work the logo overlap other elements, so it's no good.

[On pc with large window it appears like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWCSO.jpg)

[Now, on smartphone, it appears like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgnx2.jpg)

[And this is how I want it to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYFCc.jpg)

How can I solve it? I know it's a simple question, but I don't know how to do it.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-brand">
<a class="custom-logo-link" rel="home"><img src="/logo.png" class="custom-logo img-fluid" width="282" height="53"></a>    
</div>
```

Comment: Please include code. We cannot help without code.

Comment: Can you Share your expectation output on image..??? so we can clearify your problem

Comment: @RohithBalaji Sorry, I added it.

Comment: @MLuca i answered your question below if you satisying with my answer then vote up so that other people find it easily

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `@media` Query Rule For it and it can be doing on a more way but i prefers to use `@media` screen it will help you

If your screen width is under `768px` then this code will execute

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand img{
    margin-left: 120px; /* as per your requirement you can change pixels here */
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand img{
   margin-left: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-brand">
<a class="custom-logo-link" rel="home"><img src="/logo.png" class="custom-logo img-fluid" width="282" height="53"></a>    
</div>
```

Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:

- width and height of the viewport
- width and height of the device
- orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
- resolution

Using media queries are a popular technique for delivering a tailored style sheet to desktops, laptops, tablets, and mobile phones (such as iPhone and Android phones).

Read More documentation about Media Query [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

and

You can edit or preview code [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G95MUFHH4KPU)

If you know your screen resolution then you can check it [Here](http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it was one of the attempt I tried. It would solve my problem for a certain resolution, but not for every resolution. It should be something like 
margin-left: calc(50% - 105px);
where 105px is the width of the logo divided by 2. Or I'd need to set the margin from the center of the logo, or, again, get the resolution of the screen: I tried with screen.width and 50%vw, but nothing worked.

Comment: After various attempted I choose the following solution
    @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
     .navbar-brand img{
      margin-left: calc(50vw - 105px);
      }
    }
with 'max-width: 576px' cause with 767px the logo doesn't stay in the center. I'm not writing all the code, but editing a web site made with wordpress, so maybe I'm missing something.

p.s. Sorry, I indented four spaces but the text didn't change.